# Bluemix + Node.js - Is there documentation for the watson-developer-cloud module?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am interested in playing around with the Q & A service, the demo app uses the REST API and I am wondering if the service can be used with the newer watson-developer-cloud module and if so where can I find an example or documentation for those functions.

The demo is online at [Q&A Node.js demo](http://watson-qa-demo.mybluemix.net/) but this uses the older REST API.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use the service with the newer watson-developer-cloud module, but there's no updated demo.  Note, that the module was not changed drastically enough that it should really matter.

Comment: But where can I find documentation for the module? I don't have any idea what function calls to use without seeing the list... Thanks.

Comment: Found it on npm, disregard my quetsion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [README.md](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/blob/master/README.md) file for the Github [repository containing the project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/) has a full set of usage instructions.